# Submit Release APK built using Android Studio Canary

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, beta

I have just watched the Android Dev Conference videos and see there are some cool new features in Android Studio 4 (Motion Layout, Compose etc) that I would like to take advantage of.

My question is, if I build an app with a version of Android Studio that is in Canary (or Beta) am I likely to face issues being able to publish it on the store? I fully understand that the features may not be 100% complete or stable at this point. What I really want to know is a submission likely to be rejected or subject to other blockers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions/255746#255746

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there will be any issue. I have done it in past. Work like charm

Answer (score 0):

If there is any possiblity about publishing the apps on crashing you need to be sure about Google does not release that version. Because the thing, the real aim, the main goal is publishing. They're wanting the increase that developer community, make happy them and the result is going to be effect the Google Play quality.